# could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]

Tags: java, spring

При попытке приравнять результат запроса Update к int x - выходит такая ошибка,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/make-zero",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model model ) {
        try {
            int x = employeeEventRepository.setToZero();
            model.addAttribute("login", x);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
                    }
        return "redirect:/timetracking/compensatory/pereschet";
```

а запрос у меня такой

```
@Query(value = "update TT_EMPLOYEE_EVENT set status = 0  where is_approved = 1 and status = 1 and create_date < current_timestamp - numtodsinterval(30, 'minute');COMMIT ;
```

есть ли кто сможет помочь?

Comment: Простите, а чего именно Вы хотите добиться в данном примере?

Comment: Вы делаете `UPDATE` и закономерно ничего не получаете в ответ. Вопрос в том, что для Вас X... это количество записей, которые были обновлены или количество записей, которые удовлетворяют условию `status = 0` или может еще что-то?